# Fill a reactjs map with json objects from request response inside for loop

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a React dashboard and I found a library that helps me build a line chart using a json object.

So I'm trying to get 7 objects from my GET requests inside a for loop and fill the `data` map with them.

This is the json object that I get:

```
{
  "year": "2020-03-03",
  "uses": 0
}
```

I want to have an object like this:

```
data = [
  {
    year: 2014,uses: 255,
  }, {
    year: 2016,uses: 250,
  }, {
    year: 2018,uses: 540,
  },
];
```

I'm trying to fill the data map inside `componentWillMount()` like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data ,
  };
}

componentWillMount(){
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transfer/getUsesByDay/"+i).then(
      res => {
        console.log("http://localhost:5000/transfer/getUsesByDay/"+i)
        console.log(res.data)
        //TODO : set state => Fill Data
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: First thing to note: `componentWillMount` is deprecated and not suggested for use. You should use `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Second: what have you attempted so far to set the state, and what issues did you run into?

Comment: when i tried this : this.setState({data : res.data})
i get TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Comment: I don't see a `forEach` in your code?

Comment: this is why i'm stucked , i didn't use forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Promise.all to wait for all the response promises to resolve and then try to update the state at once.

```
componentWillMount() {
  let responses = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      responses.push(axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transfer/getUsesByDay/"+i))
    }

  Promise.all(responses).then(results => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
            data: [...prevState.data, ...results.map(r => r.data)]
       };
    })
  })
}
```

try `componentDidMount` instead (`componentWillMount` has been deprecated)

Comment: You shouldn't do `prevState.data =`. That mutates the state. React may not trigger a re-render.

Comment: so , what i should use instead of prevState.data ?

Comment: Thanks Brian! i have made an edit (not sure if theres any error since i did not run it myself, but conveys the idea you correctly mentioned)

Comment: Thank you for you solution , but the problem now is that i don't get the same result , axios.get doesnt seem to work in order , it executes randomly (it returns result for i = 2 , then for i equal 7 then it returns two time i = 5 per exemple)